# Help with LINQ group by

Tags: asp.net, sql, linq, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to replicate this SQL query

```
SELECT     COUNT(1) AS Records, MONTH(date) AS Month, YEAR(date) AS YEAR
FROM         tblBlogEntries
GROUP BY MONTH(date), YEAR(date)
ORDER BY year DESC, month DESC
```

Into LINQ, I've gotten as far as this:

```
var q = from Rec in db.tblBlogEntries
        group Rec by new { Rec.date.Value.Year, Rec.date.Value.Month } into G
        select new {
            Month = G.Key.Month,
            Year = G.Key.Year
        };
```

But I'm still new to LINQ and am a little lost.  Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
var query = from rec in db.tblBlogEntries 
            group rec by new { rec.date.Value.Month,
                               rec.date.Value.Year } into g
            orderby g.Key.Year descending, g.Key.Month descending
            select new {
                Count = g.Count(),
                g.Key.Year,
                g.Key.Month
            };
```

Comment: Works a charm thanks Jon!  I'm slowly getting the hand of Linq now, starting to really love it!